# Trying to install Xcode and it's just stuck with a grey circle and a blue square inside

Tags: xcode, macos

I have researched on SO and found no recent answers to this. Yes there are suggestions going back many years but none worked.

I tried to do an upgrade of install and it stuck at 75% and the blue install circle never moved after 5-6 hours.

I then deleted the application and started again.  Now it just sits there as though there is not even an internet connection and like nothing is happening.  Does anyone have suggestions on how I can debug this and find out what's happening.  Is there some log file created?  Are there files I can remove so I can start from scratch?

**Update**, now the circle just filled to 75% but it's not changing and there doesn't appear to be any more downloading happening.

Comment: IMO, it's better not to use the Mac App Store for Xcode. Download and install the version you need, when you need it, from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/